# Catch user input with alias

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

So I recently showed my friend the `wall` command.  Now he keeps using it to talk and I regret showing him.  I want to make an alias call `wall` to keep him from using it and to also prank him.  I did `alias wall="ls"` for now.  It works if the user just types `wall`, but if I type `wall Hello world` it functions like a regular `wall` command.  Is there a way where I can get the alias to capture user input and ignore that? so when he types `wall hello world` it will still function as `ls`?

Comment: If you get it working a better prank I think would be to get it to run `fortune | cowsay` (though of course you will have to install both of those packages first)! ;D

Comment: Give me a minute to finish this deathmatch and I'll answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions can take precedence over aliases and commands. You can define function in his .bashrc that will take arguments but just ignore them.

Like so

```
  wall(){ echo " just another brick in the wall "  }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so do these things:

```
sudo echo "PATH=~/.bin:$PATH" >> /home/[username]/.bashrc
sudo mkdir /home/[username]/.bin/
sudo echo "fortune | cowsay   # Or whatever command you want to run" > /home/[username]/.bin/wall
sudo chmod 755 /home/[username]/.bin/wall
```

That way, whenever `[username]` runs the command `wall` he'll get the output of `fortune | cowsay`.  Not an alias, but good enough.